# How can I loop through open tabs and save the image within each tab locally?

Tags: javascript, c#, php, html, autosave

I'm part of a team developing a business directory. We're running automated tasks on business insertions; applications which I designed and developed in C#.

We're now in the stage of inserting all the images for the businesses, and I'm using PHP to fetch the names and phone numbers of businesses in the database -> send them to C# -> C# loads a script.js that has html2canvas preloaded in it and uses the Business Name + Business Telephone to create a uniform looking image.

After this, I end up with tons of tabs (one for each business),
each having an image generated, with a URL of something that looks like this:

```
"data:image/blablablablabla40iq490rujf9nrioubioewfofhoo3po"
```

I want to use either C#, JavaScript, or PHP to automatically save generated images to a predefined local directory as JPG's, and then to close each tab. *closing the tab is not necessary as long as the images are autosaving, but it would be a bonus.*

Right now I'm manually going through 600 - 1000 tabs of images and saving them one by one.

---

TLDR;

I've got tons of images each open in a tab using JavaScript. How do I make those images save, and then close each tab, instead of going through hundreds of tabs manually.

---

**NOTE**

- I am NOT necessarily trying to force-save a file on a client's computer. I'm using apache, so I imagined it would work by sending the image data over to a .php file using ajax, then decoding it and saving it. This is what I need assistence with - or any other solution, as long as it works! :)

Thanks.

Comment: You can't force save a file on a users computer

Comment: The application/site would be running on apache localhost, that's what I meant by local... I'm sure PHP can achieve that.

Comment: So, send the images with ajax to the server, save it local, response to the browser that everything OK, than close the window. I can't understand the problem..

Comment: You can save a .png or .jpg but it's a little more difficult to save encoded data of an image. It's not an actual image...

Comment: @MoshFeu Can you help with "save it local"? That's why I asked this question.

Comment: What language you use?

Comment: I use PHP but I can use any other if it's necessary